# Is there any canonical evidence that "The Lost Village" is parody?

Tags: the-lost-village

*The Lost Village* (aka *Mayoiga*, 迷家-マヨイガ) is one of the most talked-about series of the spring 2016 series; more than one critic has called it "the comedy of the season" with the claim that the series is simply so absurd, *so* over-the-top that it has to be a deliberate parody of its genre.  See, for instance, [this AniWords column at Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-feature/2016/05/03/feature-aniwords-the-lost-village-is-the-best-comedy-of-the-season) or [this review of episode 6](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/review/the-lost-village/episode-6/.101871) at ANN.

My question is whether there's any objective evidence that the material is supposed to be parodic — if there are interviews with the director, production company materials, or anything of that sort that specifically call out the comedy aspects of the series, or whether there's some chance that all involved with the production are playing it straight and would be shocked to discover that a large portion of their viewership is laughing at the show.

Comment: I can't say if it's a parody or not, but based on my experience while watching it, it's like combination of Higurashi (cursed village) + Dangan Ronpa (extreme characteristic)... and while I expected the genre to be physiological horror based on the trailer, I laughed more than when I watched Higurashi or Dangan Ronpa because of its absurdity.